# Why has Intersango stopped accepting UK bank transfers?

Tags: exchanges, intersango

http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/ztjcf/intersango_no_longer_accepting_uk_bank_transfers/

> I hadn't been on the site in a while, but last night I sent £30 to
>   Intersango, only to find out today that they no longer accept
>   transfers. Have opened a ticket with them but am a bit worried that my
>   money will be lost in the ether!

Was the a formal announcement? Do they expect bank transfers to resume?

What's the deal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the UK, banks are free to discontinue providing a banking relationship with certain customers.  Metro Bank chose to do so with Intersango.  They now have no bank in the UK, and there is [very little trading](http://bitcoincharts.com/charts/intrsngGBP#rg180zigWeeklyzczsg2012-06-01zeg2012-09-14zm1g10zm2g25zvzcv) on their BTC/GBP market since the August 30th action as there are no methods for moving GBPs in or out..

There have been no mentions that I've seen of this being resolved anytime soon.

[image]

- http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=63877.msg1122824#msg1122824

For updates, see Intersango's [status page](https://support.intersango.com/status).

Comment: Thanks. Followup on Quora: http://www.quora.com/Bitcoin/Why-are-various-institutions-choosing-not-to-work-with-Bitcoin-businesses